# Is it possible to modify Ubuntu source code to change system language to new language?

Tags: language-support, source-code, system-language

I am an a software engineer, student, and i wanted to do my project on Ubuntu. I want to add Tibetan language as system language on Ubuntu But do not know how to start. I know python, C++, C, CSS3, HTML5. Need help from experts for guidance. 
Thank you.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that you just need to install the tibetan language files such as language-pack-bo and language-pack-gnome-bo as for other programs on the system it will depend what system they are using for translation in which case you would likely be better off contacting the upstream project most are more than happy to accept the help of volunteer translators and would be happy to point you in the right direction.

Once installed you should find the gettext files for the above in /usr/share/locale and /usr/share/locale-langpack look for ones with bo in them that's the ISO code for Tibetan if you do make any improvements consider getting in touch with the package maintainer to get them included.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But i am currently using Mac OS.  How may i get all detail files ?

Comment: I'm not really sufficiently familiar with OSX but you would probably need to browse ftp://ftp.ubuntu.com/ manually and locate the source tarballs there.